# Problems with Mol2chemfig code

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

I have to include organic molecules into a report and for that reason I wanted to use `chemfig`. After having installed the package I tested it with one of the first lines of code in the documentation: `\chemfig{A-B-[1]C-[3]-D-[7]E-[6]F}`

This was compiled without any problems. So, now I switched over to [mol2chemfig](http://py-chemist.com/mol_2_chemfig) and entered my SMILES code from ChemDraw. The interface converted it to a `\chemfig`-command which I copied and pasted into my LaTeX document.

After compiling I receive the following Error message:

> ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/dlh' and I am
>   going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

For testing reasons, I then went back to [mol2chemfig](http://py-chemist.com/mol_2_chemfig) and searched for an other molecule – in my case caffeine – in the database and copied the code of that one.

It gives an Error too:

> ! Undefined control
>   sequence.\atom@1 ->\mcfcringle {1.03}

So, it definitely seems, that something is going wrong here. Unfortunately I'm pretty new to LaTeX, and so I have no idea why I'm getting tese eroor messages.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you please post what you tried. I created a caffeine molecule using the mol2chemfig code and nothing more than `documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}`  `usepackage{chemfig}`  `begin{document}`  `\chemfig{-[:138]N-[:84]=^[:156]N-[:228]=[:300](-[:240](-[:180]N(-[:240]%
    )-[:120](-[:60]N(-[:120])-)=[:180]O)=[:300]O)-[:12]\phantom{N}}`  `\end{document}`  There is something likely wrong in your preamble.

Comment: I used the following code: `\chemfig{-[:288]N-[:234](-[:0,0.85,,,draw=none]\mcfcringle{1.03})-[:306]N-[:18]-[:90](-[:162]\phantom{N})-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:330]N(-[:30])-[:270](=[:330]O)-[:210]N(-[:150])-[:270]}`I rotated the molecule by 150 degrees and used the "fancy bonds" as well as the "aromatic" options.

Answer (score 3):

The undefined control sequence error pointing to `\mcfcringle` indicates that the `mol2chemfig.sty` file is not being found. Because `mol2chemfig` is not packaged with either TexLive or MikTeX you will need to install it manually.  See the TexLive or MikTex manual for details on how to do this. After downloading `mol2chemfig.sty` from here: http://chimpsky.uwaterloo.ca/mol2chemfig/download and installing it as a local file, the following code runs to produce the caffeine molecule.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mol2chemfig}        
\begin{document}
\chemfig{CH_3-[:108,,1]N-[:54](-[:180,0.85,,,draw=none]\mcfcringle{1.03})-[:126]N-[:198]-[:270](-[:342]\phantom{N})-[:210](=[:270]O)-[:150]N(-[:210,,,2]H_3C)-[:90](=[:150]O)-[:30]N(-[:330])-[:90,,,1]CH_3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well... I already did exactly what you described here. I have downloaded `mol2chemfig-1.4` and I put it into my packages folder. In the preamble `\usepackage{mol2chemfig}` as well as `\usepackage{chemfig}` is included. So there shouldn't be any problems?!

Comment: Are you saying you are still getting the same error as you first reported? What exactly is happening? Are you using TexLive or MikTeX? Did you refresh the packages database after the install?

Comment: I already had installed the `mol2chemfig` package... I'm using TexLive on a Mac with texmaker as code editor.